# I am getting "stale element reference" when trying to scrape using selenium, I used "await" statements as and when required but still getting error

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

async function visitMatch(matchURL,i){

```
await browser.get(matchURL);
await browser.wait(wd.until.elementLocated(wd.By.css(".cb-nav-bar a")));

let buttons=await browser.findElements(wd.By.css(".cb-nav-bar a"));
await buttons[1].click();

await browser.wait(wd.until.elementLocated(wd.By.css(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-ltst-wgt-hdr")));
let tables=await browser.findElements(wd.By.css(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-ltst-wgt-hdr"));
await browser.wait(wd.until.elementLocated(wd.By.css(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-scrd-hdr-rw")));
let teamName=await browser.findElements(wd.By.css(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-scrd-hdr-rw"));

console.log(await teamName[0].getAttribute("innerText")); //I am getting error at this line
```

}

I am getting this error on the console last line :"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

I was trying to run the function asynchronously first, but to resolve the error I am calling the above function synchronously, but I am getting the same error again and again, can someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: this can happen when the DOM is still updating.   You'll see stale element when a method is called on that webelement.  (The DOM has updated between the time you retrieved it and the time you called the method.)  In this case you need to re-get the element.  The solution is to either hard-code a sleep before the call, or functionize the findElements call and re-call if StaleElement exception is caught.

Comment: OR, check the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium