# Python selenium wait for dropdown update

Tags: python, selenium, select, webdriverwait

For some reason one dropdown list has delay on the update after another dropdown list is selected, because of that I have to use time.sleep() and I really don't like it. Is there a way to check when the dropdown is updated and put a wait on it?

```
element = Select(find(driver, "//*[@id='new-item-type']"))
element.select_by_index(random.randint(1,len(element.options)-1))
time.sleep(1)
element = Select(find(driver, "//*[@id='new-item-product']"))
element.select_by_index(random.randint(1,len(element.options)-1))
```

```html
<option data-v-16f7cab4="" value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Select Product </option>
```

All the dropdowns in my webpage already has a default option in it, so I can't check when it gets populated since it already is.

All options on subsequent dropdowns are affected by the option chosen in the previous dropdown.

Comment: You can try by checking for stale element exceptions.  These will be thrown if you call a method on a webelement when the DOM is still updating.  (You could use something like  .get_attribute to check...)  If caught re-get the Select.   Something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707  (You can just functionize and re-call when caught, too... no need for dateTime.   I would check each element in the Select before letting it go through...)

Comment: can you share a link to that webpage and clarify what dropdowns there are you talking about? I feel the information you presented here is not enough.

Comment: There's no reason not to like sleep, but you should put it in a while loop and break when you see the element you're after.

Comment: @Prophet sorry, can't do, I'm testing the website using dev logins, you won't be able to see anything without it.

Comment: No problems, but we probably will not be able to help in this case

Comment: @pguardiario that's the problem I don't know what element I'm after because the options depend on the selection of previous dropdown, and hardcoding it with all possible selections seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Just wait for them to change. You're overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
        if len(element.options) != 1:
             element.select_by_index(random.randint(1,len(element.options)-1))
            break
```

It might not be the perfect solution, but in my case it works, since there's always atleast 2 elements after choosing something from dropdown menu.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.