# How does this HTML element make a click without any link tag and how to click it via Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium

I've run into this scenario on many ocassions when I'm trying to click on a particular element via Selenium.

It's a div element and nothing happens when we click on it via automation. The strange thing is that this element tree doesn't contain any link tags.

Here's an example URL: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-ways-to-learn-programming Try clicking on the "request" button to open this dialog.

[image: photo depicting what we want to click]

I'm trying to avoid using mouse hover and instead want to click via javascript execution. I'm currently using the following code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='q-box qu-display--inline-block']/div/div/span/span)[1]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

But this click doesn't work.

1. How does this element make a click without an a-tag in normal user interaction?
2. If there exists no a-tag then is there any way to make this click via a js call?

Comment: You need to share that HTML in text format here, along with that what is the error you are facing when you used the above code ?

Comment: @cruisepandey That's a pretty long HTML and I think anyone who's eyeing the HTML might find it helpful to look around at the javascript / css or surrounding HTML in case that matters. Adding it here would add needless clutter. As for the error it doesn't throw any error. Just that the click doesn't work.

Comment: for 1) The webmaster can either place event handlers directly on the element or on a parent DOM element (event "bubbling") via javascript. (when checking for clicks on a parent the click event will have a property that is the target... ex: case/switch evt.target.id... or whatever attribute is unique about that element.)

Comment: @pcalkins Is it possible to trace those events when I make the click? Is there any way to find out more details about these events. Also, is there a term that I can google for this kind of event setting? I'm not getting what you mean by everything after "event bubbling. If you have a link or another question on SO which talks about this then that'd be great.

Comment: If you have the inspector open, you'll see a highlight/flash which indicates which handler receives the click event (it can be as far up as the <body>).  "javascript event bubbling" is exactly the term to google... I found a link that explains it pretty well here: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for replying and providing this link. I went through it and a key part to identify this seems to be that `onclick` attribute in at least one of the attributes of the tags in the entire vertical. I don't see that `onclick` attribute anywhere which makes me believe that they might be using a different method to react to that click?

Comment: It doesn't matter too much where the onclick is... just target the element that a user would click.  You can use the webdriver click method or a js click.  Be aware that when there's a space in the class name that means more than one css style is being applied.  (Your xpath there won't work because of it...)  This item has multiple class names.

Comment: @pcalkins Yeah, I've already tried clicking on every element possible starting from the parent. I'm making the clicks via JS and locating the elements via XPath. Nothing happens with those JS clicks. The XPath is correct because I've verified the XPath.

Comment: you can track the event listeners in inspector... in chrome there's a tab for "event listeners"... but you should be able to click just using the webdriver click method.   (That'll generate the full sequence of events if the page is being very picky about things... mouseover, mousedown, cursor not moved much, mouseup, then click event..)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the plus sign, you will see a message displayed on top and plus sign changes to Check mark.

See if this works

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@name='CirclePlus'][1]").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/span[@name='CircleCheckmark'][1]')))
if element.is_displayed():
    print("Invitation sent")
```

Comment: The reason why I want to avoid the direct UI interaction is because this requires us to scroll down as well for subsequent circles. And the problem that arises is that the circle exists in DOM but is covered by a layer which will cause all clicks to fail. The way out of this problem is to scroll down which comes with its own problem. Selenium's scroll into view and scroll-down is kinda flaky and unreliable. There'll be a time when you've either scrolled down too much or too less and run into problem#1 again. That's why I'm trying to make that click via javascript.

Comment: Selenium will scroll the element into view when using click() method.  Sometimes there can be an overlapping element that intercepts the click.  That might be floating footer, or a progress indicator...  determine which it is and adjust accordingly.  (webdriverwait which catches intercepting click for progress... or closing float first.)  The answer here is pretty good for progress overlays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707

Comment: @pcalkins Progress overlays are pretty easy to avoid using webdriverwait, like you suggest. I've done that several times. That is not the case over here. Here there is a block that contains all elements that I want to click on. Half of that block is covered by 2 different elements which will always be present on the screen. In order to make the click I must scroll down by the exact number of pixels that are required which is much more tricky than a temporary overlay.