# ElementClickInterceptedException Solutions in Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm going to press a button on a website as automated, but meanwhile, something called campaigns(kampanyalar) is preventing it. How can I solve this? I want the other element not to get click property

The error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div class="styled__CampaignCardDescriptionTitle-sc-1n4y3hk-2 hulWUi" color="">...</div> is not clickable at point (531, 35). Other element would receive the click: <a class="styled__HeaderMenuItem-sc-126ws66-35 gEoUee" href="/kampanyalar" id="DPE_TR_HOME_BUTTON_HEADERITEM0">...</a>
```

Comment: There are different solutions for different causes.  Sometimes there's a dialog in front that needs to be closed.  I think in your case it looks like the DOM is still being updated (though maybe it's a scroll issue).  If it's caused by the DOM still being updated (or a loading progress element showing) check the answer posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ElementClickInterceptedException` can be caused by several reasons.
The most powerful is to click it with JavaScript instead of webdriver click.  Like the following:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

However it's better to see what causes this exception.
In case the element is out of the visible screen or some footer element element overlaps it, it is better to scroll that element into the view:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

In some other case this will occur because you are trying to click the element while page is still loading elements so as some other element is currently found on that element. In this case it is better to simply wait until this element becomes clickable. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath"))).click()
```

So, it's better to use more user-similar actions according to the specific situation you are facing there and only if no alternatives to use JavaScript clicks

Comment: not so sure waiting for clickable would prevent this for all cases.  The element can be clickable, but still the click intercepted exception is thrown..

Comment: I didn't mention it will work for all the cases. Only if there is some overlapping element presented there during the rendering process.

Answer (score 1):

**ElementClickInterceptedException** means that the element you want to interact with is not available in Selenium view port.

**3 things :**

**1.** Launch the browser in full screen :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

**2.**  scroll till that element using execute_script  :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_css_selector(.your_css_selector))
```

**3.** Use of ActionChains :

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('some id where you want to go')).perform()
```

**Imports** you would need :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```