# Pause code execution if progress bar is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use this code to pause code execution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));
```

Unfortunately the html code is changed this way:

```
<ngx-spinner _ngcontent-eas-c0="" bdcolor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)" color="#0070A0" size="medium" type="square-jelly-box" _nghost-eas-c1="">
   <!---->
   <div _ngcontent-eas-c1="" class="overlay" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); position: fixed;">
      <div _ngcontent-eas-c1="" class="la-square-jelly-box la-2x" style="color: rgb(0, 112, 160);">
         <!---->
         <div _ngcontent-eas-c1=""></div>
         <div _ngcontent-eas-c1=""></div>
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-eas-c1="" class="loading-text"><span _ngcontent-eas-c0="" class="spinner">Please Wait ...</span></div>
   </div>
</ngx-spinner>
```

I tried to implement this code"

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='spinner' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));
```

But the code execution is not paused. Can you advise how to implement his properly?

Comment: Better to use wait on elements to be loaded... so if you are going to say click on an item next, use the wait and expected condition of toBeClickable on that element.  Catch click intercepted exceptions if necessary.  (Also see this answer if that becomes an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this `xpath` works.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='loading-text']/span[@class='spinner']"))
```