# WebDriver.Wait() not working inside a While loop used for infinite page scroll

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait, infinite-scroll

I want to use `WebDriver.Wait()` function inside a while loop. While loop is used for scrolling an infinite scroll website. I want to have a wait between last_scroll and new_scroll to get page content loaded. Static `time.sleep(10)` is working fine but I don't want to use it.

```py
try:
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pb-xl')))
    self.writeToFile('test.txt','Page is loaded\n')
            # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        print("Scrolling down...")
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        print("Wait for new content to load...")
        # Wait to load page
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pb-xl')))
        # time.sleep(10)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        print("Reached the end of the page.")
        last_height = new_height

        print("Loading next page")
    # print(driver.page_source)
    self.writeToFile('page_source.txt',driver.page_source)
except TimeoutException:
        self.writeToFile('test.txt','Timed out waiting for the element to appear\n')
except Exception as e:
        self.writeToFile('test.txt',f'Error: {str(e)}\n')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WebDriver.Wait() function call inside While loop is not working

Comment: "presence_of_all_elements_located" will only wait until at least one element exists.  Selenium can't know ahead of time how many elements there are...  It also can't know when the scroll is actually finished.  If you know how many elements there will be, you can program a wait for that... but otherwise, just use a sleep.

Comment: i only want to check the presence of at least one element and then scroll down. As it is an infinite scroll page so i don't exactly know fixed number of expected elements

Comment: so to avoid the sleep, you need to check if the element array has all elements.  To do that, you use some method on the elements in the array and check for "Stale Element Exception".  If you get one, you know that list is still populating and you need to re-get the element array.   Here's one of the ways to go about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707