# Selenium Wait for all elements with selector specified

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have something like this

```
el = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "till-cap"))
)
```

The problem with the above code is that it does not wait for all the element, it returns 5 instead of 12 elements, sometimes the elements could be more or less, I resolved this by using `time.sleep(15)` in python, to wait for 15 seconds. But I feel this is not the best way to resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: By using time.sleep(15), you get all of the desired elements? Is there a reason you do not want to use this method? If so, please update your question with why

Comment: Yes, I do, But I feel there are better ways to do this. Thank you

Comment: if the DOM is still populating, a Stale Element Exception will be thrown when calling a method on one of the elements.  You can catch that and re-get the array if caught.  I functionize and re-call function if caught... here's a method using time and while loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707  You can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this functionality is not a native function in Selenium, you can implement a lambda function to verify how many elements are present before moving on:

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(lambda method: len(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "till-cap")) == 12)
```

Java has Selenium-native functionality for this exact use case, but in Python we must improvise with the lambda method. To avoid a lambda, you could place your time.sleep() after the WebDriverWait function, as the rest of the elements often populate shortly after the first element:

```
el = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "till-cap"))
)
time.sleep(2)
```

This could allow you to decrease the time required in time.sleep(), but you will likely have to test a few times to see the minimum time required.

Comment: Using this approach will only check if the elements returned == 12, if elements is more or less, this will fail

Comment: You can adjust "==12" to be whatever suits you. Do you want it greater than or equal to 12? okay, use ">= 12" . If you're unsure how many elements there will be, then the "sleep()" method will be best.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure of exactly how many elements will be returned

Comment: Okay, then placing sleep after your WebDriverWait function sounds like the best solution.

Comment: Of course. Cheers, Habib!