# trying to handle the wait for spinner icon to be disappear in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

the wait spinner path

```
private @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='q-btn-group row no-wrap inline q-ma-sm no-shadow']")          List<WebElement> sendToApprovalPageLoad;
```

this is loop

```
    public void waitForSendToApprovalPageLoad() throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    while (sendToApprovalPageLoad.size() != 0 && count <= 5) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    count++;

         }
     }
```

this work but it is very slow, if anyone have better suggestion that will be helpful for me
Thank you

I want to expect it more fast way to handle the wait spinner

Comment: You can catch a clickIntercepted exception and re-get the element.  (if that's what it's preventing your next action)  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707